# C++: fopen() returns handle to empty file

Tags: c++, fopen, cstdio

I'm getting a strange file handle from `fopen`; the pointer itself isn't NULL, but the file it represents has no size, and `feof(file)` is already set...  what could be causing this?

(I triple checked the file itself, it exists, has data, and the file's permissions are okay... and `filename` is set to "source/test_file.object.txt")

```
bool tagFile(const char * filename){
    FILE * file = fopen(filename, "r");
    if(file == NULL){                        // file is not NULL
        printf("   Couldn't open the file %s", filename);
        return false;
    }
    int size = fseek(file, 0, SEEK_END); // size is 0
    rewind(file);
    while(feof(file)){

        ....  // never executes because feof(file) fails
    }
}
0x002cc410  // value of 'file' in the debugger
    _ptr=0x00000000 <Bad Ptr> 
    _cnt=0 
    _base=0x00000000 <Bad Ptr>
    _flag = 1
    _file = 3
```

Comment: Could you try `fseek(file, 0L, SEEK_END);` and `size = ftell(file);` instead of only `int size = fseek(file, 0, SEEK_END);`? In order to rewind, could you try `fseek(file, 0L, SEEK_SET);`

Comment: How do you call `tagFile`?

Comment: I feel like a total fool... the problem was a lot simpler than I thought.  `feof(file)` should be `feof(file) == 0`  the things you spot 2 minutes after asking... thank you for the help though!

Comment: Oh, God. I missed that part. You can still use !feof(file) (that's the way I use it).

Answer (score 0):

The most common cause of this is simply opening a file which is empty. There are no bytes to read so EOF is immediate, but the file exists so `fopen` can't return NULL.